# how to return 2 pairs as a result in SML?

Tags: sml

I'm a beginner at SML programming. I've written a program that takes 4 inputs, and makes some changes on them. Now I want this program to return 2 pairs as the result. This is the code:

```
fun Move(n,k,z,b): int * int =
if (n=1) then (k+1,z)
else (k,z);
```

Now in if statement I want to return for example (k+1,z) and (n,b) at the same time, instead of just (k+1,z) . Is it possible without using list(I mean to return in form of product)? If so how should I change the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you should be reading an introductory book, for example [H&R](http://www.it.dtu.dk/introSML/) or [ML for the Working Programmer](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~lp15/MLbook/).

Just like `(k+1,z)` is a product of `k+1` and `z`, you can make a product of `(k+1,z)` and `(n,b)`. Such a value could be `((k+1,z), (n,b))`, being a two-tuple of two two-tuples, or `(k+1, z, n, b)` being a four-tuple. They're isomorphic, so pick whichever you like.

In fact, the input arguments `(n,k,z,b)` might appear as if they are four distinct values, but at the same time, they're *one* product of four values. Giving your function a lowercase name as is customary in ML, and since the *if-then-else* only affects `k`, you might have:

```
fun move (n, k, z, b) = (n, if n = 1 then k+1 else k, z, b)
```

Using pattern matching rather than *if-then-else*, you might have:

```
fun move (1, k, z, b) = (1, k+1, z, b)
  | move (n, k, z, b) = (n, k,   z, b)
```

Although I'm not sure why that function makes any sense.

Comment: I made this function as a simple example to learn how to return 2 pairs. Thanks